# Do I need a helper to register my app as Login Item if app is UIElement

Tags: macos, cocoa

My app is marked as UIElement and background-only. I want it to load on login. Do I still need a helper app to start it or I can register the app itself with `SMLoginItemSetEnabled`.

Answer (score 1):

You won't need helper app. You can only register application in login items.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly spoken you need a helper app but following the instructions how to use `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` the helper app will be created automatically.